# determining if a string is a k-palindrome by not only removing first and last characters

Tags: python, python-3.x, algorithm, recursion, palindrome

I was just writing a program to determine if a given string is a palindrome when at most n letters are removed from it. I came up with a program in python which works but only by removing the first or last characters of the string recursively. It does not remove/ check what happens when you remove characters which are not on one of the ends. I was wondering how I could improve my program so that it does check all possibilities. This is my code so far:

```
def palindromecheck(s,n):
    #print(s)
    #print(n)

    if (len(s)) <=1:
        return True
    if n==0:
        return False
    
    while s[0] == s[(len(s)-1)]:
        s=s[1:-1]
        if len(s) <= 1:
            return True


    
    return palindromecheck((s[:-1]),(n-1)) or palindromecheck((s[1:]),(n-1))
```

Comment: The program looks good to me. Only the `n==0` condition should better be `n<0`. What are example cases where it fails?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a typical DP problem. You could try to use DP (memo() helper funtion to save the repetitions). The idea is to find the longest palindromic subsequence of the given string. Then
|lps - original string| <= k,
conclude that the string is k-palindrome.

```py
def checkPalindrome(s: str, k: int) -> bool:
    # memo to save the repeatition
    memo = {}
 
    def helper(start, end):
        if start >= end: return 0           # <= 1 char is a palindrome
          
        if (start, end) in memo:
            return memo[(start, end)]

        if s[start] == s[end]:
            result = helper(start + 1, end - 1)
        else:
            result = 1 + min(helper(start + 1, end), \
                             helper(start, end - 1))

        memo[(start, end)] = result
        return result

    return helper(0, len(s) - 1) <= k
```

Alternatively, you can use lru_chache for the intermediate results:

```py
from functools import lru_cache
from typing import List


def checkPalindrome(w: str, k: int) -> bool:
    @lru_cache(maxsize=None)
    
    def helper(s, e):            
        if s > e: return 0
        
        if w[s] != w[e]:
            return 1 + min(helper(s+1, e), \
                           helper(s, e-1))
        else:
            return helper(s+1, e-1)
        
    return helper(0, len(w)-1) <= k


w = "asparagus"
k = 4

print(checkPalindrome(w, k))
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I was just wondering if you are able to comment the code to explain what its doing. Im kind of struggling to get my head around it as I have not done DP before .

Comment: The code is very straightforward, if you can run it through some examples in the http://www.pythontutor.com/ - you will get more insight.  (that's how we learn at the beginning).  Glad that you can it helpful. If that's acceptable, could you vote up then?

Comment: what does '\' do in this situation?

Comment: it's the python way to say the line is continuing to next line (w/o break).  Otherwise it's hard to read and over 80-character by one line.  You could PEP (forgot the number).

Comment: ahhh I see . Also how is exactly is min() returning the minimum of the two functions being called ?

Comment: also what exactly does the result variable hold ? what does the result show?

Comment: Do you want to run the program and find out in the tool - pythontutor.com?

Comment: I have used the python tutor to run the code. It helped a bit but I am still quite confused